# Remove elements from Array of Array Swift

Tags: swift

For context I'm creating my own hashmap in swift.

I've got an element and I'm storing the elements in buckets which is an array of arrays

```
struct Element {
    var key: Int
    var value: Int
}

class MyHashMap {
    var buckets : [[Element]] = [[]]

    init() {
        buckets = [Array(repeating: Element(key: -1, value: -1), count: 2)]
        buckets.append([Element(key: 3, value: 4)])
    }

}
```

I want to remove all the buckets where the key is -1 and I'm struggling.

Flatmap does not return the right type
i.e.

```
hashmap.buckets.flatMap{$0}.filter{$0.key != -1}
```

is incorrect.

How can I remove all of the buckets with key -1?

Comment: If any of the answers has solved your issue then please mark it as accepted or give some feedback why this isn't resolved yet.

Answer (score 1):

Map the outer array to a new array of arrays, where from the inner array only the elements with `key != -1` are preserved. I would make this a method of the `MyHashMap` class:

```
class MyHashMap {
    // ...

    func compactBuckets() {
        buckets = buckets.map { $0.filter { $0.key != -1 }}
    }
}
```

Alternatively (and *possibly* more efficient), with a loop over the indices of the outer array:

```
    func compactBuckets() {
        for i in buckets.indices {
            buckets[i].removeAll(where: { $0.key == -1 })
        }
    }
```

In either case you may additionally want to remove empty inner arrays from the outer array:

```
        buckets.removeAll(where: { $0.isEmpty })
```

Comment: Doing `print(hashmap.buckets.count)` after either of your suggestions will return 2 instead of 1. There seems to be an empty array left in the `buckets` array. Notice what it says in the question "I want to remove all the _buckets_ where the key is -1"

Comment: @JoakimDanielson: I interpreted the problem as “remove all entries with key=-1 from the nested array,” not as “remove all inner arrays which have *any* entry with key=-1,” but I may be wrong of course. – You were right about the first point.

Comment: Hopefully OP will let us know which interpretation is right.

Comment: It's a hashmap. Therefore remove all entries with key=-1

Answer (score 0):

You can use `removeAll` where you filter with `contains` for the buckets

```
hashmap.buckets.removeAll { $0.contains { $0.key == -1 } }
```